# Convert string "dd month_full_name year" to string "yyyy/mm/dd" with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string, transformation

Is there anything standard in C# to transform in to out. I don't mind ad hoc routine either.

```
string in = "1 February 2001"
string out = "2001/02/01"
```

Comment: There's nothing in C#, just in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to parse the date in exact format than relying on the culture

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "d MMMM yyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1 February 2001").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you're always in the en-US culture.

```
 string in = "1 February 2001";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(in);
    string out = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning culture info... `.Parse(in, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` or `.Parse(in, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`

Answer (score 0):

DateTime out = DateTime.Parse(in);

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  DateTime dt = 
>   Convert.ToDateTime("1 February 2001", new CultureInfo("2001/02/01"));
> ```